# MIssing token when accessing a protected route using JWT Token

Tags: python, flask, jwt, token

I am trying to access a protected route "/home" using JWT token, but once I successfully connect to /home (200), I get kicked out (401 error saying token is missing).

I am trying to figure out the problem, but nothing has worked out for me. I need help.

@token_required func. This function checks the token whether it is valid or not

```
def token_required(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated(*args,**kwargs):
        token = None
        if 'Authorization' in request.headers:
            token = request.headers['Authorization'].split(' ')[1]
            print(token)
        if not token:
            return jsonify({'Alert!' : 'Token is missing!'}),401
        try:
            data = jwt.decode(token, app.config['SECRET_KEY'],algorithms=["HS256"])
            print(data)
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            print("Expired!")
            return jsonify({'message': 'Token has expired'}),401
        except jwt.InvalidTokenError:
            print('Invalid token')
            return jsonify({'Alert!' : 'Invalid token!'}),401
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return decorated
```

Login function on the backend

```
@app.route('/auth/login',methods=['GET','POST'])
def loginUser():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        username = data['username']
        password = data['password']
        if not data or not username or not password:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Missing required fields'}), 400
        if check_username_exist(username) and checkPassword(get_userID(username),password):       
            token = jwt.encode({
            'user':username,
            'exp': datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)},app.config['SECRET_KEY'],algorithm='HS256')
            return make_response(jsonify({'token': token}),200)
        else:
            return jsonify({'message': 'Password is incorrect'}),400
    return jsonify({'message': 'Could not verify', 'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic auth="Login required"'}), 401
```

Login function on the frontend

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").on("submit", function (event) {
          const userInfo = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(),
          };
          $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/login",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(userInfo),
            success: function (result) {
              const token = result.token
              localStorage.setItem("token", token);
              $.ajax({
                url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/home",
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                  "Authorization": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                success: function () {
                  window.location.href = "/home";
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  console.log(errorThrown);
                  alert("Error: " + textStatus);
                },
              });
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
              alert("Error: " + error);
            },
          });
          event.preventDefault();
        });
      });
```

Once I access to the /home route, I get the result of jwt.decode(token,app.config['SECRET_KEY'],algorithms=["HS256"]) on my terminal.
This means that the token passed from the frontend to access the protected route was successful.
However, after that, I get kicked out instantly for "Missing token" 401.

I made sure that token is saved properly in the localstorage.

One thing I have in mind is that when I checked the network tab to see whether there is an authorization header in the request, I couldn't find one. But since the token passed through the headers is validated in the first request, I thought this wasn`t a problem. I am not sure tho.